# Unable to override temporary file with `tempfile`

Tags: rust, temporary-files, rust-tokio

Getting an error when creating a tempfile for socket use.:

```
Error: Custom { kind: AlreadyExists, error: PathError { path: "/tmp", err: Custom { kind: AlreadyExists, error: "too many temporary files exist" } } }
```

---

```
use tempfile::{tempfile, Builder, NamedTempFile};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = Builder::new().prefix("testsock").rand_bytes(0).tempfile()?;


    Ok(())
}
```

Is there any way I can override the file?

Comment: Why do you use `tempfile` if you set `rand_bytes (0)`? The whole point of `tempfile` is that part of the file name is randomly generated. If you want a fixed name, use `File` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The `two many files exist` error occurs if the file it is trying to create already exists. You can solve this error by deleting the files in your temp dir. In your case this is probably in /tmp/testsock/, you may also need to remove the folder testsock if just deleting the files does not work.

---

The default temp file will be used if `.tempfile()`

However you can specify the tempfile if you use the following.

```rust
let tmp = Builder::new()
        .prefix("example")
        .rand_bytes(0)
        .tempfile_in("./")?;
```

The documentation for the tempfile builder can be found:
https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/struct.Builder.html